# Explain Tomcat Realm entry in details?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

Plenty of time i saw this entry in **context.xml** when someone doing Authentication of user from Servelt3 login method

```
<realm classname="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" debug="99"
    drivername="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"
    connectionurl="jdbc:mysql://localhost/tomcatusers?user=test;password=test"
    usertable="users" usernamecol="user_name" usercredcol="user_pass"
    userroletable="user_roles" rolenamecol="role_name"/>
```

Now in Java classes they doing something this code

```
   HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
 request.login(username, password);
```

Can anyone tell what query will fire in this case ? And how this `relm` entry will authenticate user with **username** and **password** ?

Comment: There is no debug param. Remove it.

Comment: Tomcat version? Or, rather then waiting for someone else to go and look at the source code for the JDBCRealm for the Tomcat version you are using, you could just go and look at the source code yourself. (http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat)

Comment: Tomcat version7 and no any way to check what query fire by tomcat